# Controlling percentage axis and adding values to HH Likert plot

Tags: r, graphics, plot, lattice, survey

Consider the following minimal example:

```
tab = structure(c(187, 189, 205, 167, 273, 275, 295, 231, 385, 575, 
409, 363, 899, 707, 751, 667, 2007, 1953, 2101, 2531, 1043, 1023, 
1071, 971, 385, 575, 409, 363, 181, 241, 157, 163, 123, 163, 
133, 131), .Dim = c(4L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("-4", "-3", 
"-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4")))
```

The matrix `tab` contains counts of a 9-Point Likert Scale.

A basic plot is easy to produce:

```
    likert(tab,
           auto.key=list(between=0.5, between.columns=1),
           main="Attitudes",
           BrewerPaletteName="RdBu",as.percent=TRUE, rightAxisLabels=NULL, 
           rightAxis=NULL, ylab.right="")
```

And it looks nice. Now, the problems:

- I would like to control the increments of the percentage axis. In some cases, with other counts, it only shows 50%. I want to enforce 10% increments
- I want to add the % count as a label. Most importantly for the 0-category. Like in Excel, where you right click and say "add data labels". There must be something similar.

I also considered ggplot, however, it does not support the diverging plots. Plus labeling is also quite messy, especially for tikz export.

**EDIT**
I have tried using panel.text. However, I still don't get the numbers alined correctly.

```
#does not work right!
trellis.focus("toplevel")
for(pp in 1:nrow(tab)){
panel.text(0.5, (pp/nrow(tab))*0.84+0.16, tab[pp,5], cex = 1, font = 2)
}
trellis.unfocus()
```

How can I find the right positions within each bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change `x` axis values you should add argument `scales=` and add `at=` argument for the `x` axis.

```
likert(tab,
       auto.key=list(between=0.5, between.columns=1),
       main="Attitudes",
       BrewerPaletteName="RdBu",as.percent=TRUE, rightAxisLabels=NULL, 
       rightAxis=NULL, ylab.right="",
       scales=list(
         x=list(
           at=seq(-50,50,10))))
```

Comment: Wonderful! Task one completed, it works like a charm. Any idea on the value labels?

Comment: @user1216731 do you want something like this fir labels ,   `scales=list(
         x=list(
           labels = paste(seq(-50,50,10),'%',sep=''),
           at=seq(-50,50,10))))`?

Comment: @agstudy great, now even with % sign. Thanks! What I still miss is to label the bars, i.e. put 42% on the 0-share of the first bar.

Comment: Essentially it is some form of a trellis/lattice barplot. There must be a straightforward way to put the percentages into each of the chunks of each bar.

Comment: There appears to be solution for labels, so I picked this answer as the solution for the solvable issue #1.